# Execute Linux command only if column in CSV file has a value greater than 1

Tags: shell-script, csv

I am trying to figure out a way to execute a Linux command only if a specific column in my CSV file has a value greater than 1.

Sample CSV file:

```
Item,Quantity  
Pen,1  
Pencil,1  
Stapler,3
```

Using the example above, I would like my script to check column 2 of the CSV, and if it finds value > 1 (in this case it would because of the 3) then it would run the command, and if all the values in column 2 were 1, then it would do nothing.

Can somebody help me accomplish this?

Comment: does the command need to use any of the values in the csv file as args, or does it just have to run once for each line when $2 > 1?

Comment: It just needs to execute the Linux command once for the whole file if it finds one or more instances of a value > 1 in column 2. None of the values in column two are being passed onto the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk -F, 'NR>1 && $2 > 1 {found=1 ; exit} ;
          END {exit !found}' file.csv && mycommand`

This exits with `0` (true) if any field 2 is > 1.  Otherwise it exits with 1 (false).  `mycommand` is run if true.

The `NR>1` skips the `Item,Quantity` header (the string "Quantity" evaluates to > 1).

Answer (score 2):

Check the columns with `awk` and exit with some number if they match the criteria. Then test the exit code with `$?` and run your command(s).

```
awk -F ',' '$2>1{exit 42}' file
[[ "$?" -eq 42 ]] && echo yes || echo no
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
if grep -qE ',([2-9]|[1-9][0-9])' file
then
    echo execute your command
fi
```

Comment: This will find values >1 in *any* column (other than the first), and not just in the second column.

Comment: As designed.  On the file format specified in the question this code yields the correct output.

Comment: @RobertL as much as I hate to admit it, you are absolutely correct. Have an upvote to remove that nasty negative score.

Comment: @rubynorails Thank you.  I think simple is better. I don't understand why someone (@G-Man?) would downvote something that works correctly.  Unnecessary functionality increases the chance of errors (bugs).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(cut -d, -f2 file.txt | grep '[0-9]' | sort -nr | head -1) -gt 1 ]]; then
  echo 'a number in the 2nd column is greater than 1.'
else
  echo 'i am doing nothing.'
fi
```